# How to boot a physical Linux partition with Qemu for Windows 10 X64 bit?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, virtualization, qemu

I have **Debian Linux and Windows 10** installed alongside on my first hard drive. I want to start my **Debian** install from within **Windows** through Qemu and the **Hax hypervisor**. This is how is partitioned my disk :

1. 190 GB NTFS with Windows 10
2. Recovery partition of Windows 10 = 486 mb
3. extfs4 partition with Debian = 120 GB
4. free space = 4 GB

When I'm on **Windows**,I use a **linux file system** to read and write on the linux partition...with it i can associate a new drive letter to it. So,I would like for example give to **QEMU** the drive letter where is stored **Linux**,but I don't know how to do that...this is the qemu commands sequence that I use usually to boot Linux...

```
C:\Programmi\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3072 -cpu Haswell,vendor=GenuineIntel,+invtsc,vmware-cpuid-freq=on -machine pc-q35-2.9 -smp 4,cores=2 -usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet -smbios type=2 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-duplex **-accel hax** -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,drive=DebHDD -drive id=DebHDD,if=none,file= **WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE ?**,format=qcow2 -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,drive=DebDVD
```

How would I make it work?

Comment: I arrived here looking for the the answer to this after several hours of search. There are plenty of tutorials on how to boot a *windows* image form a physical partition in a Linux host, but no information at all on the opposite: Start Linux (guest) from a physical partition on a Windows (host) . Even QEMU documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer very deep in the documentation:

https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#host_005fdrives

> Hard disks 
>   Hard disks can be used with the syntax: \.\PhysicalDriveN
>   where N is the drive number (0 is the first hard disk). /dev/hda is
>   supported as an alias to the first hard disk drive \.\PhysicalDrive0.
>
> WARNING: unless you know what you do, it is better to only make
>   READ-ONLY accesses to the hard disk otherwise you may corrupt your
>   host data (use the -snapshot command line so that the modifications
>   are written in a temporary file).

Comment: How well did this work?